# Como enviar parametros a servio soap en php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estoy intentando enviar un parametro de filtrado a una funcion que define un web service soap. He intentado enviar un arreglo asociativo con los nombres de los campos que se describen en el wsdl, un objeto simpleXmlElement y una clase stdClass y en todos el mismo resultado.(el recurso solicitado no existe) casi como si no enviara nada.
Pero cuando prueb este servicio en SOAPUI para el mismo valor de firltrado que uso en php, obtengo los datos esperados.

Que estoy haciendo mal ?, ya no se como mas probar

Aqui una porcion del codigo que estoy usando

```
        $client = new SoapClient('miUrl?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
        $client->__setLocation('urlDelServicio');

        //Fijamos header de autentificacion
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($this->generateWSSecurityHeader());

        $params = new stdClass();
        $params->suid='miValorDeFiltrado';        

        
        $response = $client->seleccionarUsuario($params);
```

Ese es un ejemplo de envio de parametros como stdClass, he intenado enviado un arreglo y xml y el mismo resultado

Aqui la definicion del wsdl del web service

```
<element name="requestsu">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="suid" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
```

Y este es un ejemplo del xml que envia SOAPUI(el cual si obtiene resultados)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sel="http://UserData/seleccionarUsuario">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sel:requestsu>
         <sel:suid>miValorDeFiltrado</sel:suid>
      </sel:requestsu>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Revisa el resultado de `$client->__getLastRequest()` -después de llamar al servicio- y compáralo con tu ejemplo de SOAPUI.

Comment: Me retorna null al realizar ese llamando.  Y claro, como se observa en el ejemplo, trace => true